MERN Stack app is running properly in local server but after deployed to production could not read MongoDB data
api/index.js
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello from Node API server!");
});

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello!");
});

app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoutes)
app.use("/api/v1/user", userRoutes)
app.use("/api/v1/product", productRoutes)
app.use("/api/v1/order", orderRoutes)

app.listen(port, () => {
    connectDB()
    console.log(`${chalk.green('✓')} ${chalk.blue(
        `Listening on port ${port}. Visit http://localhost:${port}/ in your browser.`
    )}`)
})

db/connect.js
import mongoose from "mongoose"

export const connectDB = async() => {
    try{
        console.log(process.env.MONGO_URI)
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
    } catch(error){
        console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

api/routes/productRoute.js
router.get('/', getAllProducts)

api/controllers/productController.js
export const getAllProducts = async(req, res) => {
    try{ 
        const products = await Product.find({})
        console.log(products)

        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            products
        })
    } catch(error){
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Error in fetching products!",
            error 
        })
        console.log(error)
    }
}

After I deployed the MERN Stack project to vercel, the api controllers could not read MongoDB data even I passed the MONGO_URI in environmental variables settings. It shows the error message MongooseError: Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout.<anonymous> that I could not figure out since when running on local it could show out data. Also I checked clearly that I had already whitelisted IP address in MongoDB Network Access
I successfully deployed the app but the api still not working correctly so may need some help

does this console.log(MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}); print?
It's a common error that gets triggered when DB when you try  to access models before creating the connection with the database.

If in production mode how to view the logs?

Check this https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms

I found solution that after I changed the connectDB() put in front of the script it works

The link I shared also state the same that you did.
